# It's possible in C# to save different typed interfaces into one variable?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have the interface:

```
public interface ISlot<TType>
{
    TType Slot { get; }
}
```

And then 2 classes implement it:

```
public class DungeonInventorySlot : ISlot<DungeonInventorySlot>
{
    DungeonInventorySlot ISlot<DungeonInventorySlot>.Slot 
    {
        get { return this; } 
    }
}

public class ActiveSkillSlot : ISlot<ActiveSkillSlot>
{
    ActiveSkillSlot ISlot<ActiveSkillSlot>.Slot 
    {
        get { return this; } 
    }
}
```

Now on a controller class I want to have a variable to hold one of this at any given time (there may be more than 2 in the future):

```
public class BattleFlow
{
    private ISlot<> HoldSlot;
}
```

Is this possible in C#? what would be a good approach to this problem?

Currently I have several variables one per type, although, only one is set at any given time.

Comment: A slot only has a getter? If that's right, you could declare it as `ISlot<out T>` and use `ISlot<object>` for the field. This is called generic variance (specifically covariance here) if you want to read more about it.

Comment: @mikez: variance applies only if the type parameters are in fact related somehow. I don't see anything in the question that suggests that's the case. The OP would have to use `System.Object` as the base class, unless there's additional information they haven't shared.

Answer (score 0):

Using some base class and making `ISlot` interface with `out` template parameter:

```
    public interface ISlot<out TType>
    {
        TType Slot { get; }
    }

    public class BaseClass
    {
    }

    public class DungeonInventorySlot : BaseClass, ISlot<DungeonInventorySlot>
    {
        DungeonInventorySlot ISlot<DungeonInventorySlot>.Slot
        {
            get { return this; }
        }
    }

    public class ActiveSkillSlot : BaseClass, ISlot<ActiveSkillSlot>
    {
        ActiveSkillSlot ISlot<ActiveSkillSlot>.Slot
        {
            get { return this; }
        }
    }

    public class BattleFlow
    {
        public ISlot<BaseClass> HoldSlot;
    }

    private void Test()
    {
        var s = new BattleFlow();
        s.HoldSlot = new ActiveSkillSlot();
        s.HoldSlot = new DungeonInventorySlot();
    }
```

Comment: The original question makes no mention of this mythical `BaseClass` you've introduced in your answer. The best we could hope for given the question that was actually written (as opposed to the question you seem to have wished was written) is to use `System.Object` as the base class. It's the only class in common we actually _know_ the type parameters must have.